# Call parent function that was written to parent from iFrame in IE8

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue in IE8. I have an iframe as follows.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script id="myscript">
function foo() { alert('foo'); }
</script>


(function () {
    var pdoc = parent.document;
    var dest = pdoc.head;
    var text = document.getElementById("myscript").textContent;

    var pscr = pdoc.createElement("script");
    pscr.textContent = text;
    dest.appendChild(pscr);

    parent.foo();
})();
</body>
</html>
```

The iframe copies the script to the parent and runs the function **foo** on the parent.

This works perfectly well on all the browsers I need it to except for IE 8.
(This is not a cross domain issue)

I get "**Object doesn't support this property or method**"

Comment: Most of your code is not even inside a `<script>` element. Could be a problem wtih `textContent`, IE uses (used to use) `innerText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older IE doesn't have `textContent`. It has `innerText`, but for `script` elements you use `text` instead.

Separately, `document.head` isn't automatically provided on IE8; use `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` instead.

With those two changes, this works on IE8, IE11, current Chrome, and current Firefox:

```
(function () {
    var pdoc = parent.document;
    var dest = pdoc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.getElementById("myscript");
    var prop = 'textContent' in script ? 'textContent' : 'text';
    var text = script[prop];

    var pscr = pdoc.createElement("script");
    pscr[prop] = text;
    dest.appendChild(pscr);
    parent.foo();
})();
```

---

Of course, doing this via text is only useful if you need the new `foo` function to close over the other window's global context. But presumably that's what you're trying to do...

Comment: "close over the other window's global context", Im not sure I follow

Comment: @spinners: E.g., you want to use globals in `foo` that are defined by the parent window, not the iframe's window. (Two such globals that come to mind are `window` and `document`...)